# Is it slower to use the * operator in XPath rather than using explicit path names?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have two questions that may have the same answer:

> (1) Say I have an XML parent element "Parent" with any number of child
>   elements that can only be titled either "Child_A" or "Child_B". If I
>   want to access all of those child elements, is it slower to use an
>   XPath expression like "/Parent/*" rather than to be explicit and use
>   "/Parent/Child_A | /Parent/Child_B"?
>
> (2) Similarly, if I am working on one XML block that I now know is
>   Child_A and I want to access an ID field that is present on that
>   element, is it significantly slower to use an XPath expression like
>   "/*/ID" rather than "/Child_A/ID"?

I may do some performance testing, and if so I will post the results here as well, but I wanted to understand the answers to both of the above questions from a logical perspective. Thanks!

Comment: What XPath engine are you using? This is going to give you different results between different engines.

Comment: Your question reflects an entirely wrong way to ask about, or even think about, performance: (1) There's a very high chance that any performance difference is inconsequential in practice.  (2) Few performance answers transcend implementations and environments, neither of which you've specified.  (3) Performance often depends upon characteristics of the data, which again, you've not specified.   In short, if you have a true performance issue, you know because you've measured an actual problem; anything else is worse than premature optimization -- it's just premature worrying.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat what others have said in comments:

(a) it depends on the XPath implementation, and

(b) it's unlikely to make a difference to the bottom line.

Do you have a performance problem? How far short of your performance target are you? Whether you're 5% short or 50% short, I doubt this change is going to help you achieve your performance requirements. There are almost certainly other things you can do to the application that will have a much bigger impact.

It's very likely that most XPath processors will implement child::* as "scan all the child nodes and select those that are elements", and will implement child::A as "scan all the child nodes and select those that are elements and are named A". If that's the case, then the second strategy is clearly going to take a microsecond or two longer. But some processors might index the children by name, in which case finding elements by name might be faster.

For a practical illustration of that, you will often read advice against using `//X` to find X elements at every level of the document; instead they will tell you to use an explicit path like `/A/B/C/X`. But some processors, including Saxon, will see `//X` and build an index, meaning that the `//X` strategy becomes faster -- at least if it is used repeatedly.

The only way to find out is to measure it. But before you spend any time on it, unless it's just out of idle curiosity, first study your application top-down to discover where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Say I have an XML parent element "Parent" with any number of child
>   elements that can only be titled either "Child_A" or "Child_B". If I
>   want to access all of those child elements, is it slower to use an
>   XPath expression like "/Parent/*" rather than to be explicit and use
>   "/Parent/Child_A | /Parent/Child_B"?
>
> (2) Similarly, if I am working on one XML block that I now know is
>   Child_A and I want to access an ID field that is present on that
>   element, is it significantly slower to use an XPath expression like
>   "/*/ID" rather than "/Child_A/ID"?

Both answers are negative -- as already explained by Dr. Kay.

When the expected schema (structure) of the XML document is well-known, and we know that the current element has only one type of child element, I would recommend (and often do so myself)  using the abbreviated form `somePathExpressionToTheParent/*` because it results in shorter expressions and aids readability.

Certainly, when an element has more than one type of element children and we need to follow only one of the possible paths, then the exact name of the child element needs to be specified.